# How to Determine Notification Large Icon Width and Height & Big View Image Width

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm adding a notification and trying to determine the size of the Large Icon (the icon on the left when the notification is viewed) size.

I'm creating an icon dynamically and want to get it in the right proportions.

Also, when setting the notification Big View to be a picture, how can I determine the width? (Documentation state that the height id 256 dp).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the height and width of large icon at run time using `android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_height` and `android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_width` respectively (API Level 11 and above).

Answer (score 0):

Using C# with Xamarin for Android, the code looks like this (`TheActivity` is an instance of your Activity class):

```
    var MaxWidth = (int)TheActivity.Resources.GetDimension(Android.Resource.Dimension.NotificationLargeIconWidth);
    var MaxHeight = (int)TheActivity.Resources.GetDimension(Android.Resource.Dimension.NotificationLargeIconHeight);
```